# How do I exclude certain elements using xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm working on a Scrapy project and I've got the following bit of HTML I'd like to capture, using XPath:

```
<table id='foobar'>
    <tr>
        <td><p>....</td>
        <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script type='text/javascript'>...</script></td>
        <td><p>.....<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><p>.....</div></td>
        <td><script type='text/javascript'>...</script></td>
    </tr>
    <!--repeat for another 250 or so rows-->
</table>
```

It's a mix of table data in `<div>`s and `<p>`s, with a bunch of script tags thrown into the mix. Sometimes the `<script>` tags are inside the `<div>`s, making this a bit more complicated. Basically what I need is the WHOLE table, but not the script tags or their contents. The XPath was originally:

```
//table[contains(@id, 'foobar')]
```

but that doesn't exclude the script tags, so I changed it to

```
//table[contains(@id, 'foobar')]//script/*[following-sibling::* and preceding-sibling::*]
```

thinking that will work, but. Is this possible to do in xpath or am I just better off just grabbing everything from the table, iterating over the contents, and removing anything that has 'text/javascript' in it?

Comment: Since you're using `Scrapy`, you can just extract the items exactly what you want in table using xpath (exclude script tags), no need to grab everything. But if the project is smaller, getting everything first just isn't a bad idea neither.

Answer (score 2):

use `//*[not(self::script)]` can exclude all child nodes with `<script>` tag

```
from lxml import etree

# you have invalid closing tags which I have fixed on my string
s = '''
<table id='foobar'>
    <tr>
        <td><p>....</p></td>
        <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><script type='text/javascript'>...</script></td>
        <td><p>.....<br /></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div><p>.....</p></div></td>
        <td><script type='text/javascript'>...</script></td>
    </tr>
    <!--repeat for another 250 or so rows-->
</table>
'''

tree = etree.fromstring(s)

for each in tree.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'foobar')]//*[not(self::script)]"):
    print each.tag

tr
td
p
td
div
tr
td
td
p
br
tr
td
div
p
td
```